I am trying to make a java websocketWhen I am trying to connect to websocket, I am getting following error : Request method 'GET' is not supported
Pom.Xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
              <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
               <version>3.4.1</version>
         </dependency>
         
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>





WebSocket controller :
@CrossOrigin(origins ="*")
@RestController
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketController {

    @Autowired
    private FutureService futureService;

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private FutureAlertRepository futureAlertRepository;
    
    
     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
     @GetMapping("/futuresget") 
        public ResponseEntity<List<List<Map<String, Object>>>> fetchFutures() {
            List<List<Map<String, Object>>> futures = futureService.fetchDataFromApi();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(futures);
        }



     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
        @GetMapping("/futuress") 
        public void sendUpdates() {
            List<List<Map<String, Object>>> updatedData = futureService.fetchDataFromApi();
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/futures", updatedData);
            futureService.updateDatabase(updatedData); 
        }

Websocket Configuration: 

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableWebSocket
@CrossOrigin(origins ="*")
public class WebSocketConfig implements  WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); 
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS();
    }
    

        
    @Bean
    FutureHandler customFutureHandler() {
        return new FutureHandler();
    }
    
    
}

Future Handler :
@Component
 public class FutureHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

     @Autowired
     private FutureService futureService;

     @Override
     protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException {

         try {
             if (message.getPayload().equals("testFetchFutures")) {
                 List<List<Map<String, Object>>> futures = futureService.fetchDataFromApi();
                 String jsonData = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(futures); 
                 session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(jsonData));
             } else if (message.getPayload().equals("testSendUpdates")) {
                 sendUpdates();
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Error sending data: " + e.getMessage()));
         } catch (Exception e) {
             session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Error processing message: " + e.getMessage()));
         }
     }

     public void sendUpdates() {
         List<List<Map<String, Object>>> updatedData = futureService.fetchDataFromApi();
         futureService.updateDatabase(updatedData); 
     }
 }

I tried reading documentations and tried to search on internet for long, but I didn't get proper solutions
Im trying to test it with Postman i get this error : Could not connect to ws://localhost:8081/users/topic
i tried to search on internet for long, but I didn't get proper solutions.
